# Rails gem for adding an on site tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know of a gem for rails to add a tutorial to a site?

Something like a step by step tutorial that a logged in user can follow when they come to a site. It would have things like:

- a sequence of steps or lessons to progress through
- the ability to mark lessons as done either by the user or within the site
- the ability to skip steps/lessons
- turn the tutorial on or off for the user

Online games often have an introductory tutorial like this and I'm just wondering if there are any gems to shortcut setting one up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know a specific gem to do an onboarding tutorial but there is this javascript plugin which would help you:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

Here a gem to easily include it into your app

https://github.com/TrueNorth/joyride-rails